# Magento Transactional Email - Order Confirmation Email

Tags: magento

Running on Magento C.E v1.7

I've changed the style of the Order Confirmation Email, and all was looking good until recently the Subtotal, Shipping & Handling, Grand Total Column became another style. This occurs randomly as some of the OC emails were ok.

These are the paths I've make sure everything is alright:

> 1) email > order > item > order > default.phtml 
>   2) Grand Total:    tax > checkout > grandtotal.phtml#
>   3) Total:  sales > order > totals.phtml#

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different customer groups? These pages that you check are irrelevant with your email i think. 
Please take a look on that: 
[Changing email template…](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40257/)

Comment: I don't have different customer groups. The issue here now is the style (only at Subtotal, Shipping & Handling, not the entire email) is **randomly** not working.